# jquery format json and display as a ul >li

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting the following json string after the data has been posted via an ajax request.

```
{
 "first_name":["The first name field is required."],
 "last_name":["The last name field is required."],
 "email":["The email field is required."],
 "usercode":["The usercode field is required."],
 "password":["The password field is required."],
 "password_confirmation":["The password confirmation field is required."],
 "captcha":["The captcha field is required."]
}
```

what i would like to do is to parse the above string and display them as `li` elements.

I am doing something like the following

```
for(var i=0;i<=json.length;i++)
{
     $('#errorArea > ul').append("<li>" + json[i] + "</li>")
}
```

but I am not getting the expected result.

Can you please let  me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your javascript code? How are you assigning `json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is being parsed to an object, and objects in JavaScript don't have a `length` property, only arrays and array-like objects do.

Instead, iterate over the object with

```
for (var i in json)
```

Your other line, inside the loop, would remain unchanged.

Comment: I did what you suggested and I get the following result .all the letters are new li tags

Comment: In that case your JSON is still a string and has not been parsed to an object, either by jQuery (as the result of a `data-type: "json"` request) or manually via `JSON.parse()`. You didn't include that part of the code, so I made the assumption. If your JSON is not being parsed, that's your first problem.

Comment: works perfectly. I used JSON.parse() and it works fine. thanks.. i am going to mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is object, so use $.each.

```
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
  $('#errorArea > ul').append("<li>" + value + "</li>")
});
```

Comment: i did what you suggested but the ul list is empty. Nothing is getting populated.

Answer (score -1):

Are you getting a JSON string or a object created from the string? Your code example looks like an object.

I would recommend to parse the string into an object and use it like

```
$('#errorArea > ul').append("<li>" + json_object.first_name + "</li>")
                     .append("<li>" + json_object.last_name + "</li>")
...
```

Comment: This is quite a laboring, non-iterative way of going about it; if the JSON has new properties in it in the future, a new line of code would be added.